# java: keep tracking of file size on the run?

Tags: java, io, size, compression, objectoutputstream

I wrote a code that writes compressed objects into a file, My questions is: is there a way that I could keep track of the increment of size of my file as the object being wrote in? here is my code:

```
public static void storeCompressedObjs(File outFile, ArrayList<Object[]> obj) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    GZIPOutputStream gz = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        gz = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(gz);
        for (Object str : obj) {
            oos.writeObject(str);
            oos.flush();
            //I was hoping to print outFile.length() here, but it doesn't work
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        oos.close();
        gz.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

I tried to use `flush` after every `oos.writeObject(str);` and then get the file size by using `outFile.length()`, but no matter how much I flush it, the file size remain unchanged until the last jump to its final size. Anyway that I could fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Apache Commons* project provides a class [CountingOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html), which you can put into your chain of `OutputStream`s. You can even have two of them:

```
package so5997784;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.CountingOutputStream;

public class CountBytes {

  private static void dump(File outFile, Object... objs) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    try {
      CountingOutputStream compressedCounter = new CountingOutputStream(fos);
      OutputStream gz = new GZIPOutputStream(compressedCounter);
      CountingOutputStream uncompressedCounter = new CountingOutputStream(gz);
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(uncompressedCounter);

      for (Object obj : objs) {
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush();
        System.out.println(uncompressedCounter.getByteCount() + " -> " + compressedCounter.getByteCount());
      }
      oos.close();
      System.out.println(uncompressedCounter.getByteCount() + " -> " + compressedCounter.getByteCount());

    } finally {
      fos.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File outFile = new File("objects.out.gz");
    dump(outFile, "a", "b", "cde", "hello", "world");
  }

}
```

Comment: When I was calling the method, I got
`8 -> 10
12 -> 10
18 -> 10
26 -> 10
34 -> 10
34 -> 51` Why is there 5 10s there, shouldn't it be incrementing?

Comment: Anyways, this achieves what I want, Thanks so much for your help

Comment: This is because `GZIPOutputStream.flush()` *does not* flush its output, maybe to guarantee some compression level or because the file format doesn't allow for it.